# Wrong route in AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I am using the same html-page for creating an new rma and editing the old one. I am trying to implement routing in AngularJs but it is not working when choosing to edit old object from a list of rma list.

**Routing**

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/rma', {
    templateUrl: 'views/rma.html',
    controller: 'RmaCtrl'
  })
  .when('/rma/:rmaId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/rma.html',
    controller: 'RmaCtrl'
  })
  .when('/rma-list', {
    templateUrl: 'views/rma-list.html',
    controller: 'RmaListCtrl'
  })
```

**RMA list controller**

```
        $scope.updateRma = function (rmaId) {
            console.log("updateRma---->" +rmaId);
            $location.path('/rma/'+rmaId);
            console.log("2. ABSURL---->" +$location.absUrl());
            // ABSURL---->http://localhost:8383/RmaClient/app/index.html#/rma-detail/%5Bobject%20Object%5D

        };
```

**rma-list.html**

```
<td><a ng-click="updateRma(rma.rmaId)" class="btn btn-small btn-success">edit</a></td>
```

**rma controller rma.js**

```
angular.module('rmaClientApp')
    .controller('RmaCtrl',
            function ($scope, $location, rmaService, $routeParams) {
                console.log("------RmaCtrl------" +$routeParams.rmaId);
                //When creating a new one, should be 0
                $scope.editMode = ($routeParams.rmaId === "0");
                if ($scope.editMode) {
                    console.log("----Creating a new RMA-----");
                    $scope.rma = rmaService.get({id: $routeParams.rmaId});
                    //console.log("$scope.rma --->" +$scope.rma);
                    $scope.rmaService = rmaService;
                } else {
                    console.log("----Editing an old RMA rmaId: "+$routeParams.rmaId );
                    var rma = $scope.rma;
                    $scope.rma = rmaService.get({id: $routeParams.rmaId});

                }
```

**rmaService**

```
angular.module('rmaServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('rmaService', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource(

                    'http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.sako.rma.rma/:rma:rmaId',
                    {},
                    {

                        update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: 'rmaId'} }
                    });
        }]);
```

**Problem**

In server side the REST-service is working fine, but when trying to edit rma number 7 in client side, I just got a blank page and error message. This link returns the corrent rma whit ID=7 and the link is:

```
http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.ako.rma.rma/7
```

When I am trying to choose the same rma from the web page the link is following:

```
http://localhost:8383/RmaClient/app/index.html#/rma/7
```

**Error**

```
------RmaCtrl------7 (12:28:34:557)
```

at app/scripts/controllers/rma.js:13
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array

Errorline is this: **$scope.rma = rmaService.get({id: $routeParams.rmaId});**

Comment: could you try adding href="#" to the anchor tag? Also add params: {id: 'rmaId'}, isArray: false so that it will look for object than array.

Comment: For editing also you are calling the get. You should call something like rmaService.update().

Comment: When trying to call update()--->Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) (12:58:36:638 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.sako.rma.rma?id=rmaId

Comment: paje007 - I am using the same service to get a list of rmas as well. I tried and exactly the same error message. update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: 'rmaId'}, isArray: false }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource url should be

```
http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.sako.rma.rma/:id'
```

then

```
http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.sako.rma.rma/:rma:rmaId'
```

as you passing only one parameter `rmaId`

```
   angular.module('rmaServices', ['ngResource'])
        .factory('rmaService', ['$resource',
            function ($resource) {
                return $resource(

                        'http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.sako.rma.rma/:id',
                        {id:"@id"},
                        {

                            update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: 'rmaId'} }
                        });
            }]);
```

Comment: Still the same error message: ------RmaCtrl------6 (13:05:30:598)
  at app/scripts/controllers/rma.js:13
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12)
    at angular.module.provider.$get.Resource.(anonymous function).$http.then.value.$resolved (app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:587:25)

Comment: @Sami that means your backend returning array of rma's instead of one rma

Comment: No it returns only one RMA: <rma>
<created>2015-04-07T11:41:07+03:00</created>
<rmaId>7</rmaId>
</rma>

Comment: @Sami is your backend returning XML ?

Comment: No, it's returning JSON and XML. Json is like: {
created: "2015-04-07T11:41:07",
rmaId: 7
}

Comment: @Sami change then url to http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.sako.rma.rma/:id'

Comment: that was it.  That errormessage is quite annoying, it doesn't tell anything. Thank you very much! Now I recognised that I have the next problem, when inserting nested objects via JPA to DB, rma as a mother object didn't get auto generated id's of its children objects. So this is the correct syntax: 'http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.ako.rma.rma/:id',
                        {},
                        {
                            
                            update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: 'rmaId'}}
                        });